# Adding animation via jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery code that insert a html after a specific `<TR>`

```
$("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr").after(row);
```

Works fine, but I would like to add a animation to this.

I try the following

```
$("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr").after(row).animate({
                      height: "18px",
                      opacity: 0.25
                  , 500);
```

Works fine,

But when I try

```
$("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr").after(row).slideDown(1000);
```

Nothing happened. Somebody can help me to put the `slideDown effect` ?

Comment: The element needs to be initially hidden before it can slide down, add a `hide()` before the `slideDown()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#imgDiminui_" + Id).closest("tr").after(row).hide().slideDown(1000);
```